# Rails 4 Login Via Sub domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, cookies, ruby-on-rails-4, session-cookies

I have a rails 4 application withs subdomains.

Each user that is registered has a subdomain which he uses to use the whole system.

Here is the issue I am running into

The user logs in using a url like sub.lvh.me/login, once logged in I redirect the user to a url on his subdomain something like sub.lvh.me/home, but he is logged out as soon as he gets there. The session information is wiped out.

Here is what I have in my session_store intializer

```
Repvista::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_repvista_session', domain: :all
```

shouldn't this work ?

Update:

I noticed that If I login using the main domain lvh.me and then go to sub.lvh.me I am logged in I want to be able to login via the sub domain url.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is from the [Wikipedia Page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie)

> The cookie domain and path define the scope of the cookie—they tell the browser that cookies should only be sent back to the server for the given domain and path. If not specified, they default to the domain and path of the object that was requested. An example of Set-Cookie directives from a website after a user logged in:

---

> Set-Cookie: LSID=DQAAAK…Eaem_vYg; Domain=docs.foo.com; Path=/accounts; Expires=Wed, 13 Jan 2021 22:23:01 GMT; Secure; HttpOnly
>
> Set-Cookie: HSID=AYQEVn….DKrdst; Domain=.foo.com; Path=/; Expires=Wed, 13 Jan 2021 22:23:01 GMT; HttpOnly
>
> Set-Cookie: SSID=Ap4P….GTEq; Domain=.foo.com; Path=/; Expires=Wed, 13 Jan 2021 22:23:01 GMT; Secure; HttpOnly
>
> ......

---

> The first cookie LSID has default domain docs.foo.com and Path /accounts, which tells the browser to use the cookie only when requesting pages contained in docs.foo.com/accounts. The other 2 cookies HSID and SSID would be sent back by the browser while requesting any subdomain in .foo.com on any path, for example www.foo.com/.
>
> Cookies can only be set on the top domain and its sub domains. Setting cookies on www.foo.com from www.bar.com will not work for security reasons.

Hope this helps you understand how session cookie scope works.